# Do not crash the system (everything segfaults) when the USB OS shortly disconnects

Tags: usb, 21.10, read-only

I dropped my computer onto the ground and the disk was broken. Therefore, I installed the OS on a USB. However, it sometimes disconnects at any time, during contributing Wikipedia, online chatting, and even online lessons! I've tried a lot of software solutions, they *helps*, but this still happens, so I think that's a hardware problem and cannot be easily solved.

The error message spamming the console was something telling me that "I cannot access the disk cause it is read-only". So, any way to remount the disk R/W when the disk shortly disconnects and block all R/W requests (accept them, but pending) during the disconnect time?

Edit: smart: unknown usb storage

Comment: Software cannot solve a hardware problem! The file system turning read-only is often a sign of a failing hard drive. It is a failsafe to prevent corruption when a hardware fault is detected.

Comment: If a *file-system* flips from RW to RO, it's because of errors being detected (*and flipping to RO prevents dataloss*), and all you can do is look at logs to find out why. It's usually the result of bad power, or faulty components unless mistakes were made by the owner of the equipment of which we have no details. We cannot see your logs, but from your description I'd be validating the hardware.

Comment: How do you know the *"disk was broken"*? Please see my initial/partial answer and report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: BTW that’s an Kubuntu on SD to USB adapter

Comment: Being on flash card; USB memory stick, HDD, SSD or in fact any type of *block device* media has the same reaction/responses...

Comment: I am gonna make a note here.  you indicated that you dropped the laptop and then it broke the disk.  any chance your other components are also damaged?  power, motherboard, hardware controllers, etc?  USB and SD devices dont 'disconnect' randomly usually, so other system damage is a possible factor here

Comment: Disk was broken: that’s my old disk, it can spin but nothing can detect it.

Comment: @Emoji Take it to a service shop.

Comment: What’s “it”? The usb or the computer?